# Executing python script usng Runtime.exec in scala not working when executed from intellij

Tags: python, scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to execute a python script from scala object. So, I am using following code for this -

```
object a extends App{
    val process:Process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 file.py")
}
```

In file.py I am saving pandas dataframe to a csv file. When I am running the scala file through intellij, it gives me an exit code 0 but there is no csv file created.

And when I am doing -

```
scalac a.scala
scala a
```

Its creating the csv file successfully. I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong here. Can someone help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using Runtime.exec() instead of the standard [ProcessBuilder](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html)?

Comment: Ohh, I didn't think about that. Thanks. 
Got it working now.